# How can I use my desktop PC as part of my laptop?

Tags: ubuntu, remote-access

I am running Ubuntu 9.04 on my machines at home. But my laptop is getting older and some tools run very slowly on it (esp Ruby on Rails, javac/java Tomcat6). However these tools perform very well on my PC so I'd like to know a way to use its power on my laptop.

I have already tried out the remote desktop tool but I don't like it. I am searching for a tool which lets me write code on my machine and - for example - I can use javac xy.java - java xy or run ruby script/server on the desktop from my laptop, and see the output in my terminal, or use the laptop's browser to see my rails project.

Comment: Related question: http://superuser.com/questions/1585/whats-the-best-remote-desktop-application

Answer (score 2):

[1] Try to explore platform LSF (Load Sharing Facility) tools. You can run such a tool on your PC (which is the faster of the two) and from your laptop, you can remotely fire 'jobs' on your it. In this context, try to explore the features offered by ubuntu cloud edition (http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/private).

[2] You can always ssh into your PC and work remotely from there (though this might not be what you are looking for).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I give a try to ssh, and have a look at LSF.